# Create table in bigquery fails when the JSON key contains hyphen

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-bigquery

I have a **JSON** data from Firebase Backup.
Data generated is such that every key is preceded by a hyphen.

Sample data is as follows:

```
"-GuGCJDEprMKczAMDUj8":{"deviceId":"399a649c6cee6209","dow":"Thursday","downloadFlag":"N","event":"streamStart","halfHourFull":"18h1","liveFlag":"Y","localDate":"2009-01-01","localHalfHour":1,"minutesSinceMidnight":1080,"quarterHourFull":"18q1","stationName":"hit 105","streamListenMethod":"Headphones","timestampLocal":"2009-01-01T18:00:33.679+10:00","timestampUTC":"2009-01-01T08:00:33.679Z"}
```

When we are trying to load that data into Bigquery then we are encountered with the below mentioned error:

> Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with
>   a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long.

Is this a bigquery limitation? 
If yes, then what's the proposed solution here.

Any help/suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a bigquery limitation? If yes, then what's the proposed solution here.

You need to use different field names instead. One option is to load the data into a single `STRING` column, e.g. by using `'CSV'` for the format with a field delimiter of `'|'` (or any other character that doesn't appear in your data). Then you can use the `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR` function to extract fields from the JSON, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE dataset.table AS
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_string, '$.-GuGCJDEprMKczAMDUj8.deviceId') AS deviceId,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_string, '$.-GuGCJDEprMKczAMDUj8.dow') AS dow,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_string, '$.-GuGCJDEprMKczAMDUj8.downloadFlag') AS downloadFlag,
...
FROM dataset.single_column_table
```

Comment: My JSON is a single line and it's very huge thus It looks like the number of columns in the schema causes too much overhead when trying to load the data. isn't there any option in bigquery wherein I can ignore specific keys of JSON while loading the data.

Comment: Check out the `ignoreUnknownValues` option for load jobs.